# Facebook Integration Error

Tags: android, facebook

I am using this [tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/android-facebook-login-example/) for facebook integration in android.After successfull importing fscebook sdk,successfully linked the facebook SDK with my project as per the tutorial.But now my project full of error in all facebook lib links.Anything I am missing?
[image]

Comment: clean and do build project

Comment: build project?? sorry, i am new to android

Comment: tell us, are you using eclipse or what? and i guess eclipse.

Comment: project-> build automatically, if this option is not checked the right click on project and click build project

Comment: Build automatically already checked

Comment: @Shivanshsaini yes, eclipse

Comment: if you know how to clean a project in eclipse then do it, if you don't.. then search for it, anyways the clean projects option is usually in top bar's project menu.

Comment: yeah did it.but still all errors are there.

Comment: Have you downloaded the Facebook SDK into your computer?
If so, have you added the Facebook SDK project into eclipse?
If so, are you 100% sure you're adding it as a Library into your own Eclipse project?

Comment: @corvuszero I did it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937030/facebook-integration-errors-in-eclipse this my another post about it

Answer (score 0):

After looking lots of error , it seems application is not able to find facebook sdk lib. 
Please check in Project -> Properties -> Android - > Library
check facebooksdk entry should be here.
If entry exists,please perform clean and build.